What is difference between putting const as reference and value?
I mean what is difference between :  "  const list =[1,2,3]" and "var list= const[1,2,3]"

The main difference is immutability.
const list =[1,2,3] This is create constant list where list is mutable. So, you can modify it's element but you can't change list reference.
var list= const[1,2,3]  In this case we create variable list where value is constant. In this case both list and reference are immutable. So we can't modify element of list nor assign difference list.
const list1 = [1, 2, 3];
var list2 = const [1, 2, 3];

list1[0] = 5; // This is allowed
list2[0] = 5; // This give you compilation error


try to run your code because it will produce unexpected results (then refactor your answer), your contribution is appreciated.

This is wrong and should not be the accepted answer.  Both cases will create an immutable List object. The only difference is that the second version allows the variable to be reassigned.

The difference is in the immutability and the way the list is declared.
const list = [1, 2, 3] declares a constant list, that is a compile-time constant, meaning its value is determined at compile time and cannot be changed at runtime.
var list = const[1, 2, 3] declares a variable that holds a constant list, but the value of that variable can be changed to a different list later in your code.
void main() {
  const list1 =[1,2,3];
  var list2 = const[1,2,3];
  
  list1.add(4); // <--error
  list2.add(4); // <--error
  list1 = [5]; // <--error
  list2 = [5];
  list2.add(6);
  print(list2);
} 


This answer will explore that problem deeply:
each value stored in the memory must have a reference to point to its location within that memory.
var list = [1,2,3];

list : is a reference variable that point to an array of integers which equal to [1,2,3] stored in the memory.
Now coming to the problem:

putting const in front of the value:


var list= const [1,2,3]

The value stored in the memory [1,2,3] is marked as const, where const means: that object is completely constant (compile time constant), actually this object and it's children if any.
but the reference variable still not constant, it's mutable (can be changed to point to any other values of the same type):
list[0] = 10; // fail, because it points to a constant value
list = [5,6]; // pass (just point to another value)
list = [4]; // pass

You only have got a free reference variable, but constant value.

Using const to declare the reference variable:


const list = [1,2,3];

declaring that reference variable as const makes the following:

the reference variable is completely immutable
the value which is pointed to by that reference is also completely
immutable.

which means any change is forbidden:
list[0] = 5; // fails

list = [2,5] // fails 

You have got a completely immutable term of both variable and value (value can't be changed and variable can't reference another value).
Hope it helps you.
